# Docker's --memory switch does not work as expected

Tags: memory, memory-management, docker

**Preamble**

I'm writing a little presentation to list some of the "gotchas" when using Docker, and I've run into one of my own.

While explaining the perils of letting Docker run without memory restrictions I've found it doesn't behave the way I expected.

I created a docker image with a PHP script that will recursively create arrays to use up memory, reporting on how much memory is currently used. The script kills itself at 1gb if no memory restriction is put in place.

You can get the image here: https://hub.docker.com/r/gisleburt/my-memory-hog
You can see the source code here: https://github.com/Gisleburt/my-memory-hog

My expectation was that the following would prevent the script going beyond 128mb of memory.

```
docker run -it --memory=128m --memory-swap=0 gisleburt/my-memory-hog
```

However, on OSX (both native, and docker-machine using the virtual box driver), the docker actually the script *just* before 250mb. On Ubuntu the script reaches 1gb and kills itself.

Weirder still, if we inspect what's happening with `docker stats`, we can see that the container actually *doesn't* go over it's memory limit. In fact, running with `--memory=4m` on Ubuntu, `docker stats` still says it doesn't use more than the 4mb, even though the script completes at 1gb. On Mac, restricting to 4mb kills the script around the 5-6mb mark.

I assume I'm missing something about the way that memory is allocated, but I can't work out what it is.

**Question**

Why does the script in the docker container appear to use more memory than the docker container? What is happening with the memory inside and outside of the container?

**Version Info**

Mac Client:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:        Thu Oct 27 00:09:21 2016
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

Mac Native:

```
Server:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:        Wed Oct 26 23:26:11 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Mac Virtual Box Machine:

```
Server:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:        Thu Oct 27 00:09:21 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

Ubuntu Client:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:        Wed Oct 26 22:01:48 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Ubuntu Engine:

```
Server:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:        Wed Oct 26 22:01:48 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of a number of people in our tech department, and in particular one member of our platform operations team, we worked out what's going on, and it *is* mentioned in the [reference guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/runtime-constraints-on-resources).

> `--memory-swap` Total memory limit (**memory + swap**, format: <number>[<unit>]). Number is a positive integer. Unit can be one of b, k, m, or g.

To put is plainly, `--memory-swap` is the total amount of memory available, both resident, and swap.

In order to get the desired effect, you must run:

```
docker run -it --memory=128m --memory-swap=128m gisleburt/my-memory-hog
```

In this example `memory = 128mb`, and `memory + swap = 128mb` therefore `swap = 0`.

It also makes sense that you can not specify a number for `--memory-swap` that is greater than 0, but less that `--memory`.

Additionally, while `--memory-swap=-1` gives you an "infinite" amount of memory via swap, for some reason, setting `--memory-swap=0` seems to make memory and swap **the same size**, giving you a total amount of memory twice what you were expecting.

You can also turn off swapping using `--memory-swappiness=0`. Although the swap file might be created, it will not be written to, and therefore will not take up any further disk space than an empty file.

**TL;DR:**

```
--memory = RES
--memory-swap = VIRT = RES + SWAP
```